# Unable to permit additional parameters in devise#accept invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm unable to permit additional parameters in `invite#accept`. I've setup everything and here's a controller.
But in the method `accept_resource` there're still only 3 old parameters accepted, other didn't come through, although they present on a form.

```
class MyInvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
    puts "edit...."
    super
  end

  private

  def accept_resource
    puts "accept_resource..."
    resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)

    # but it still permits only :password, :password_confirmation and :invitation_token
    resource
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    puts "configure_permitted_parameters..."
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:aaa, :bbb, :ccc, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                                      :invitation_token])

  end

  def update_sanitized_params
    puts "update_sanitized_params..."

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:aaa, :bbb, :ccc, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                                      :invitation_token])
```

How to fix that?
I use devise 4.2 and devise_invitable 1.6

Answer (score -1):

Try remove

```
 if: :devise_controller?
```

in your before_filter, because your are not in devise controller.